# Decay of Dirichlet exterior problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Assuming $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n, (n\ge 3)$ is a domain. Consider the Dirichlet exterior problem
\begin{align}
&\Delta u = 0 ~~~~x\in \mathbb R^n/\Omega\\
&u|_{\partial \Omega} =1  
\tag{1}
\end{align}
How to show $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} u(x)=0$ ?

In fact, in my reading book, consider a big ball $B_R(0)$ such that $\Omega \subset B_R(0)$, consider the follow problem
\begin{align}
&\Delta u = 0 ~~~~x\in B_{R}(0)/\Omega\\
&u|_{\partial \Omega} =1,~~~~~u|_{\partial B_R(0)} =0 
\tag{2}
\end{align}
Then (1) is the limit of (2) as $R\rightarrow \infty$, so $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} u(x)=0$. But I feel this statement is unconvincing.

Comment: The assumption is that $n \ge 3$, right?  Otherwise $u(x) = 1+ \log|x|$ gives a counterexample with $\Omega = B(0,1)$.

Comment: @Glitch  Yes, I miss it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The result isn't true regardless of the dimension. Consider for instance the function $u =1$ identically.  This is clearly harmonic and satisfies $u=1$ on $\partial \Omega$.  Perhaps the authors of your text have build the limit condition into the definition of solution they're using?